# LDAP: error code 34 - Incorrect DN given

Tags: spring-security, active-directory, ldap

I am new with active directory and spring security, in fact, I want to change my spring security configuration so that use active directory in authentififcation so I use this in my SecurityConfig:

```
@Autowired
public void configureGlobal(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
    auth.authenticationProvider(activeDirectoryLdapAuthenticationProvider());
    auth.eraseCredentials(false);

}

@Bean
public AuthenticationProvider activeDirectoryLdapAuthenticationProvider() {
    ActiveDirectoryLdapAuthenticationProvider authenticationProvider = new ActiveDirectoryLdapAuthenticationProvider(
            "dc=example,dc=com", "ldap://localhost:10389/dc=example,dc=com");

    authenticationProvider.setConvertSubErrorCodesToExceptions(true);
    authenticationProvider.setUseAuthenticationRequestCredentials(true);
    authenticationProvider.setUserDetailsContextMapper(mapper);

    return authenticationProvider;
}
```

and active directory studio I have a partition: `dc=example,dc=com` which contains an entry `ou=people`.

When I try to put a username and password I have this error:

> javax.naming.InvalidNameException: [LDAP: error code 34 - Incorrect DN given : admin@dc=example,dc=com (0x73 0x79 0x73 0x61 0x64 0x6D 0x69 0x6E 0x40 0x64 0x63 0x3D 0x70 0x75 0x70 0x70 0x75 0x74 0x2C 0x64 0x63 0x3D 0x63 0x6F 0x6D ) is invalid]
>       at com.sun.jndi.ldap.LdapCtx.processReturnCode(LdapCtx.java:3076)
>       at com.sun.jndi.ldap.LdapCtx.processReturnCode(LdapCtx.java:2883)
>       at com.sun.jndi.ldap.LdapCtx.connect(LdapCtx.java:2797)..

Have you any idea please?

Comment: If you're on Mac make sure you don't have any `&quot;` in your build.xml file

Answer (score 1):

`ActiveDirectoryLdapAuthenticationProvider` is intended to let you authenticate with usernames in the AD-specific form `user@example.com`, which are not standard LDAP DN format. As such, the first argument in the constructor should be the domain (`example.com`) not an LDAP DN. When you log in as `admin`, the code uses the configured domain to build the string `admin@example.com` and passes that to AD.

Since you are using `dc=example,dc=com` as the domain name, you end up with `admin@dc=example,dc=com` which is invalid.

Comment: Thank you for your answer but I tried this before and I have the same error [LDAP: error code 34 - Incorrect DN given : user@example.com

Comment: The `user@domain` name format will only work for the domain that AD is configured to authenticate for. It's almost irrelevant that it uses LDAP under the hood. If you have created some other partition I doubt if it will work and you will have to use a plain LDAP approach.

Comment: Thank you Mr.Shaun but what do you mean by use a plain LDAP approach?

Comment: I mean you will have to treat AD as a standard LDAP server. However if you are new to LDAP, AD and Spring Security then it will probably be a struggle and you'll need to do some research. I would recommend you start with a plain Java LDAP client, written in a simple `main` function (no Spring), and see if you can get that to successfully bind as your user first.